# onekeydown returns "Process" string for each keyboard press in Firefox 65.0 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ubuntu-18.04, firefox6

I'm using Firefox 65.0 for my web development. My project code contains password input. I developed this before more than a year ago using JS code that detects the key presses using `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` functions. It works fine for all browsers except the new Firefox version 65.0

My code is similar to this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=password id="button" autocomplete_="off"></input>

<script>
  $("#button").keydown(function(event) {
    console.log("key: " + event.key);
  });

  document.getElementById("button").onkeydown = function(event) {
    console.log("key: " + event.key);
  };
</script>
```

For both cases the `event.key` value is not the pressed button, but it's just `"Process"` as a string. Does someone have an idea why I get this result? How can I solve it and detect the real pressed key value?

My OS version: is ubuntu 18.04

**Edit: add debug screen shot**

In addition I can't find any attribute under event that can help me

you can find below a screen shot of a debug in the onkeydown handler for the case of 'a' key.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different event properties for key codes, and they all return something a little bit different. Try `event.which`, and if that doesn't work, [here's a list of other event properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

*Edited to provide additional info*

I did some testing, the cause appears to be that your trying to log keypresses on an input of type="password". I tested your code snippet in Firefox after removing the type="password" and both `event.which` and `event.key` work normally. I suppose its intentionally obfuscated by Firefox to avoid scripts logging password keystrokes. If you need the value of the password, use `event.target.value` in the event listener. Also I would recommend using the 'keyup' event rather than keydown, or you run into the problem of the listener repeatedly firing when you hold down a key.

**With the password attribute**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="button" autocomplete_="off"></input>

<script>  
  // Either remove the password type on your button, or access the event.target.value property and slice out the last keypress
  document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
   console.log(`Which: ${event.which}, Key: ${event.key}`);
    console.log(`Value: ${event.target.value}`);
  });
</script>
```

**Without the password attribute**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button" autocomplete_="off"></input>

<script>  
  // Either remove the password type on your button, or access the event.target.value property and slice out the last keypress
  document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
   console.log(`Which: ${event.which}, Key: ${event.key}`);
    //console.log(`Value: ${event.target.value}`);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I can't find any property that can help me
Please check my edit

Comment: I added some additional info to my answer, check it out and see if you can work with that

Comment: thank you your answer is helpful. I can use event.target.value to get the pressed key like that
event.target.value[event.target.value.length -1]